# Rails: How to show if value already exists in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, shopify-app

My app imports products from a Shopify store. It needs to cater for products that have previously been imported in to my apps database and also show any new products that have been added to the Shopify store since the last import.

My view is:

```
  # All new products in Shopify
  <% @products.each do |product| %>      
        <tr>
            <td><%= product.id %></td>
            <td><%= product.title %></td>
       </tr>  
   <% end %>

   # All existing products in my app
   <% @myproducts.each do |myproduct| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= myproduct.id %></td>
            <td><%= myproduct.title %></td>
        </tr>       
   <% end %>
```

The part of `ProductsController` controller responsible grabbing these is:

```
   @products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all)
   @myproducts = Product.where.not(id: nil)
```

The issue is that the first each loop displays *all* products from the Shopify store, including those products already in `@myproduct.each do` loop. So we end up having a lot of double-ups.

**I need `@products.each` loop to only display products where `product.id` does not already exist as `myproduct.id`.**

Should I be using an if statement in my view or some conditions in `@products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!
`ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all)` will fetch all the products in the store.
so you need to add the condition into your controller.

Option1

```
@myproducts = Product.where.not(id: nil).select(:id, :title)
@products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all)
myproducts_titles = @myproducts.map(&:title)
@products = @products.reject do |product|
  myproducts_titles.include? product.title
end
```

Option2

```
@myproducts = Product.where.not(id: nil).select(:id, :title)
myproducts_titles = myproducts.map(&:title)
@products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all)
products_titles = @products.map(&:title)
newproducts_titles = products_titles - myproducts_titles
@products = @products.select do |product|
  newproducts_titles.include? product.title
end
```

I'm not sure whether which options are much faster

Comment: Thank you @Junsuck Park. It seems we posted a reply within a minute of each other.  I am going to rewrite my attempt to be much closer to your Option 1. Thank you very much for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I tried something myself. I introduced:

```
@productIds = Product.pluck(:product_id)
```

Then a new loop:

```
 @products.delete_if do |product|
  if product.id.in?(@productIds)
    true 
  end
end
```

Seems to do this trick for now.